# Why do I need to override method not even implemented in superclass?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a plain FriendsController class which is UICollectionViewController subclass, so when I implement UICollectionViewDataSource protocol required functions why do I need to put override key word in front of func declaration it is even do not implemented in UICollectionViewController parent class.

```
class FriendsController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  fileprivate let cellId = "cellId"
  var messages: [Message]?


   override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = "Recent"
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionView?.register(MessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    setupData()

   }


 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let count = messages?.count {
        return count
    }
     return 0
}
```

I've seen that UIViewCollectionController did not implement protocol required functions:

```
  open class UICollectionViewController : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


public init(collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout)

public init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)

public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)


open var collectionView: UICollectionView?


// Defaults to YES, and if YES, any selection is cleared in viewWillAppear:
// This property has no effect if the useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions property is set to YES
open var clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear: Bool


// Set to YES before pushing a a UICollectionViewController onto a
// UINavigationController. The top view controller of the navigation controller
// must be a UICollectionViewController that was pushed with this property set
// to NO. This property should NOT be changed on a UICollectionViewController that
// has already been pushed onto a UINavigationController.
@available(iOS 7.0, *)
open var useLayoutToLayoutNavigationTransitions: Bool


// The layout object is needed when defining interactive layout to layout transitions.
@available(iOS 7.0, *)
open var collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout { get }


// Defaults to YES, and if YES, a system standard reordering gesture is used to drive collection view reordering
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
open var installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement: Bool
  }
```

Comment: What you see in Xcode is not the actual source code for UIkit

Comment: So func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) already been implemented?

Comment: Yes, in `UICollectionViewController`

Comment: but why it doesn't mentioned about it anything? If it is please where can i see actual source code for UIkit ?

Comment: Mentioned where?  The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcontroller) lists the inheritance and conformance. In order to conform to a protocol a class must implement the non-optional functions, so its implementation of that function can be inferrred.

Comment: In order to conform to a protocol a class must implement th Enron-optional functions it turns out it did not been implemented already? according to your words, and if it did not there is nothing to override we just need to implement new function to confirm our protocol conformance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163868/discussion-between-paulw11-and-n-khasanov).

Answer (score 2):

`UICollectionViewController` conforms to `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` so it has to implement the required methods of those protocols, including `numberOfItemsIn:`, which is why you need to use `override`

Comment: i thought we've to override methods already been implemented and in my example there is no implemented methods, what do you think about it?

Comment: `UICollectionViewConteoller` implements those methods which is why you need to override that implementation.

Comment: please see my question again cause i ve added explicitly what UICollectionViewController implements. (taken from xcode) so there is no implemented method.

Comment: `numberOfItemsInSection` is not optional, so despite what you see in Xcode `UICollectionViewController` must implement it in order to conform to the data source protocol.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a superclass, much rather a protocol, which your class needs to conform to.